# Rectangular array physical in memory order

Tags: .net, arrays, memory, multidimensional-array

In C, in array say `A[2][3]` rightmost index change resulted in a smallest memory address shift, i.e. elements were located in memory as `A[0][0], A[0][1]...`

Is same is true for rectangular arrays in .NET? If we have, say array `a[2, 3]` are elements located in memory as `a[0, 0], a[0, 1]...`?

Comment: You're not exactly comparing comparable. Your C array is not really a 2D array, it's an array of arrays. You can do the same in C# too: e.g. `int[][]`, not `int[,]`.

Comment: @svick you are just plain wrong.

Comment: No, that's how 2D arrays are implemented in C. They're just a 1-dimensional array whose elements are themselves 1-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @CodyGray except the formal definition and notion, they are direct analogue of rectangular arrays in C#. While `int[][]` in C# is totally different thing, and is analogue to `*int[]` in C.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [CLI specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm), section 8.9.1, states:

> Array elements shall be laid out within the array object in row-major
>   order (i.e., the elements associated with the rightmost array
>   dimension shall be laid out contiguously from lowest to highest
>   index). The actual storage allocated for each array element can
>   include platform-specific padding.

So the answer is yes -- you will first encounter all elements of the first row, then all elements of the second row, etc (as the spec says, this is called *row-major order*).